# how to create a DLL for all language

Tags: c#, java, c++

how to create a file DLL, so all language dev can used it
i think, if use C++ to created , then language .Net can used it.
however, how about JAVA ??? and a few other language

Answer (score 5):

The only guaranteed way to make a DLL that is consumable by other platforms and languages is to write it a language/platform that exports static C functions; the easiest way is to write in C and C++ directly, though other languages can too. That way you can call it from C, C++, .NET/C#/VB (using `DllImport` P/Invoke), and Java (using JNI). Other languages also support importing C functions.

(Generally) you cannot export classes or other types. If your C functions use structs then you must document those in a header file or other definition for your DLL's consumers to use.

There are other approaches, including COM (which supports exporting interfaces and other types) and the new WinRT Metadata format, but this is new and has not seen wide deployment. And COM is an exercise in pain.

Comment: +1 although the restriction to "C or C++" is highly misleading/incorrect.

Comment: -1. COM is not a pain, at least if you use it with ATL. Global functions, THAT is a pain, because you lose all OOP, and it requires duplicating code (in all languages other than C++) for structures that have to match the exact layout of the C++ structures, etc.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf sorry, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @user1610015 For anyone coming from a VB, C# or Java background, ATL is just as mysterious and impenetrable as COM itself.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. COM is not really mysterious and impenetrable (it's really simple in concept), it's just the low-level aspects that bog you down, and that's exactly what ATL hides from you.

Answer (score -4):

Java and other languages other than C#, C, and C++ can't use dlls made as C code. They're completely different languages, with Java using a Java Virtual Machine to run just-in-time bytecode, and Ruby/Python/other scripting languages using an interpreter. In fact, dlls themselves are only part of C/C++/C#. C# only is able to use C/C++ dlls because Microsoft intended compatibility.

On the other hand, you might try creating wrappers so other languages can use the code you created.

Comment: -1 this is just incorrect. C# can consume DLLs using "platform invoke". Java can consume them using JNI and its newer family member that I don't recall name of. Ruby/Python in their way, and so on. DLLs are themselves language independent.

Comment: We have Delphi using a C++ dll. More evidence this is not true.